# Google datalab errors install Nvidia driver and starting docker container

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'm following https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart (`datalab beta create-gpu [datalab-instance-name]`). The instance gets created, but the docker container fails to start:

`$docker ps -a`:

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
e44d71c07f6e        gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-gpu-installer:latest   "/bin/sh -c /entry..."   13 minutes ago      Exited (2) 12 minutes ago                         awesome_brattain
56e54c3d3f6d        gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-gpu-installer:latest   "/bin/sh -c /entry..."   14 minutes ago      Exited (2) 13 minutes ago                         naughty_montalcini`

Hard to read, but they are all STATUS=Exited

**The first bad thing I can see:**

`$ sudo journalctl --since yesterday -fu docker.service` has a strange error: 
`Apr 22 20:53:30 seth2 dockerd[668]: time="2018-04-22T20:53:30.717669594Z" level=error msg="containerd: start container" error="oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\\"/content/datalab/notebooks\\\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory\"\n" id=4795b951f1dbae3a23dae67c2d5aaa7a8bc61e1f4fd6ec58814d241da75b245f`

And surely, there is no /content directory. gcloud lists the disk as READY.

**The second bad thing I can see:**

`$ docker logs e44d71c07f6e` looks fine until the end:

`[INFO    2018-04-22 20:56:33 UTC] Running Nvidia installer
/usr/local/nvidia /
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.81.run: 1: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.81.run: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
s`

I'm pretty much ready to call this beta functionality a dumpster fire, at least for someone with my novicity with respect to GCP, and try another provider.

**Anyone have any ideas I might try though?** Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you hit this.

This is a new bug for which we have [a fix](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/pull/1994), but that fix has not yet been released (our release process takes at least a week).

The issue was a recent change to the [Container Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) tooling that broke support for older Nvidia drivers.

The fix is to update the driver version used by Datalab instances.

Until the fix makes it out into a release, you can work around the issue by downloading [the source code for the tool](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/tree/master/tools/cli) and run that version instead of the released version.